# Shortcut to "Follow TCP Stream"

Tags: wireshark

When working with TCP streams in Wireshark, I used to do the following steps:

```
Right click -> Follow TCP Stream
```

It then got even trickier in newer versions:

```
Right click -> Follow -> Follow TCP Stream
```

Which leads us to my question:

Is there an quicker way to reach this feature?

I can't seem to find a keyboard shortcut defined under the Analyze menu or in the [Wireshark manual](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChAdvFollowTCPSection.html).

Comment: AFAIK there isn't, but anyway this question is not referred to programming at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is now a default keyboard shortcut for this in Wireshark. Not sure when it was added but it is available in my version (3.0.5).

Windows:

> **Ctrl + Alt + Shift + T**

Answer (score 1):

Apply this patch with `patch -p1 < follow-tcp-stream-f3.patch` to the source directory of [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/download/src/):

```
 ui/gtk/main_menubar.c | 2 +-
 ui/qt/main_window.ui  | 3 +++
 2 files changed, 4 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)

diff --git a/ui/gtk/main_menubar.c b/ui/gtk/main_menubar.c
index 76bafd1..08d7615 100644
--- a/ui/gtk/main_menubar.c
+++ b/ui/gtk/main_menubar.c
@@ -1435 +1435 @@ static const GtkActionEntry main_menu_bar_entries[] = {
-   { "/Analyze/FollowTCPStream",                            NULL,       "Follow TCP Stream",                    NULL, NULL, G_CALLBACK(follow_tcp_stream_cb) },
+   { "/Analyze/FollowTCPStream",                            NULL,       "Follow TCP Stream",                    "F3", NULL, G_CALLBACK(follow_tcp_stream_cb) },
diff --git a/ui/qt/main_window.ui b/ui/qt/main_window.ui
index 667a3e2..6325616 100644
--- a/ui/qt/main_window.ui
+++ b/ui/qt/main_window.ui
@@ -1685,0 +1686,3 @@
+   <property name="shortcut">
+    <string>F3</string>
+   </property>
-- 
2.4.9 (Apple Git-60)
```

After building Wireshark, you can then use `F3` to follow TCP streams.